# Toshiba Satellite L70-C bios password reset

Tags: laptop, bios, toshiba-laptop, password-recovery, password-protection

I need to reset the bios on a Toshiba Satellite L70-C.

The computer was taken to a repair shop before they got me to look at it and someone there removed the cmos battery and didn't put it back... This means that the date is not remembered on power loss but the password still persist.

I removed, HDD, CD drive and RAM chips but I still can't see any obvious pins I can short.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to do this in a very dangerous way...

I could not read the number (*`MX25L6473E`*) on the chip so I photographed it first... Then I looked at its [pin configuration](https://www.macronix.com/Lists/Datasheet/Attachments/7380/MX25L6473E,%203V,%2064Mb,%20v1.4.pdf) and with a paperclip I shorted the `SDI` pin (5) with `GND` pin (4) while turning on the laptop. To avoid burning the chip, I shorted it intermittently, 1 second on, 1 second off till the BIOS menu appeared. It took me a few attempts but eventually it worked.

This is a crazy thing to do and it was really my last resort - as far as I was concerned the laptop was ready for the bin so it was worth a go... I am sharing this because it worked for me but don't blame me if you burn your chip / board.

[image: Motherboard BIOS chip]

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if you can reset this.

Try starting in BIOS (F1 or F2 repeatedly at startup).  Does this work?  I have my doubts but try it.

Then if it works, F9 in BIOS to reset, save and restart.

Most likely, you may need to replace the motherboard.

** I assumed you put in a new battery

Comment: I did not put a new battery in... i don't think it will make a difference.